# glReadPixels read failed on second-time

Tags: opengl, opencv, glreadpixels

Following code works fine

```
const char *title = "glReadOutput";
Mat out1, out2;

out1.create(screenHeight,screenWidth, CV_8UC3);
out2.create(screenHeight,screenWidth, CV_8UC3);

RenderObject();
glReadPixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (uchar*)out1.data);
//flip(out1, out1, 0);
imshow(title, out1);
waitKey(5000);

RenderObject();
glReadPixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (uchar*)out2.data);
//flip(image, out2, 0);
imshow(title, out2);
waitKey(5000);
```

However, when I transfer glReadPixels to function it works fine on first call but fails/read nothing on second call :(

```
RenderObject();
displayImage(out1);

RenderObject();
displayImage(out2);
.
.

void displayImage(Mat& image) {

  //glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
  //glPushClientAttrib(GL_CLIENT_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);

  glReadPixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (uchar*)image.data);

  //flip(image, image, 0);
  //glPopClientAttrib();

  const char *title = "glReadPixels";
  imshow(title, image);
  waitKey(5000);
  destroyWindow(title);
  //image.release();
}
```

Few points:
The thread is also same.
There is only single buffer.
Same behavior with framebuffer object (FBO) as well as glut window. I also tried glPushClientAttrib(GL_CLIENT_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS), you could see code is commented. I also called  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); on RenderObject().

Can you please help me, where might be possible mistake?

EDIT: Christian .. thanks! Your are right. But Why that is happening. There is no link on image.data with buffer right? after finishing the read? Or is it ... the display window taking over ownership of gl buffer and something wrong going on while we destroying that?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your first example works fine, because you both times display `out1` in `imshow`. Otherwise, in the function you destroy the window and then use it again in the next function call, problem?

**EDIT:** The display window doesn't take ownership of the image (and surely not of your GL frame buffer, why and how should it), but destroying a CV window (with `destroyWindow`) and then using this window again (in the `imshow` of the next function call) is surely not a good idea. I think `imshow` doesn't create a new window each time it is called, it uses a window you created with `namedWindow` and in the second function call this window doesn't exist anymore, as you destroyed it with `destroyWindow`.

Comment: Christian... thanks! you are right. I have edited question. After reading there is no link between buffer and image.data (uchar w * h storage only) right? Also buffer data.... or do u think display window take over buffer ownership? and destroy the window destroy the butter etc?

Comment: @Christian: imshow create the window itself if already not exist with given name. Anyway to verify the things... I did following experiment: first call RenderObject then glReadPixels then imshow and then destroyWindow. Second call RenderObject then glReadPixels then observe data (i.e. no imshow, so no again destroyWindow). image.data read nothing :( (i.e. garbage as it was before passing to glReadPixels) .... I am sure you are aware that new OpenCV version support OpenGL ... so I strongly think there is something going on under-the-hood.

Comment: @Christian: I posted new question as I found different cause than in begining: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386591/opencv-2-2-window-causes-problem-on-opengl

Comment: @Rudi Ok sorry, didn't know that it creates the window automatically. Then I suppose there's really something strange going on under the hood.

Comment: @Christian: after whole day struggle- found the answer. Please have look! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When OpenCV was built using 'WITH_QT_OPENGL', above problem occures.

**Solutions:**

1. Build OpenCV without 'WITH_QT_OPENGL' option.  It will completely removes all errors.
2. Or to work around- Re-attach the draw buffer (i.e. glDrawBuffer only with default buffer object or with framebuffer object (FBO) both FBO and texture/render buffer, you could valid this using 'glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT);' )